# Make backbone.js tag have Javascript syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, tag-highlighting

I spend a lot of time retagging [backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js) questions to add the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag so the code will be syntax highlighted. Would it be a good idea to set the [backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js) code language to Javascript?

Answer (score 4):

done, should be sorted now. We need to make that change manually.