# Could the d3.js tag be associated with Javascript?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467196/map-custom-value-field-to-x-value-when-using-a-stacked-layout) in the [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) and noticed the code wasn't highlighted. I think it would be appropriate to associate [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) with the Javascript language, similar to for instance [backbone.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129898/make-backbone-js-tag-have-javascript-syntax-highlighting).

I know how to get the highlighting to work: tag it with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) or use [Syntax highlighting language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints). I could do that, but (as I see it now) it's a d3.js question. If I'd tag it with Javascript, that would be just to get the highlighting. I wouldn't tag an asp.net question with c#, just to get the highlighting to work.

If that is the preferred way instead of requesting associating a tag with a language, I'll be happy to do that, just let me know in an answer here.

Comment: @Close voter: why is this off topic?

Comment: Why would you not also tag that question with `javascript`?

Comment: Well, I could do that, but (as I see it now) it's a d3.js question. If I'd tag it with Javascript, that would be just to get the highlighting. I wouldn't tag an asp.net question with c#, just to get the highlighting to work. I'll edit my question a bit.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I do see a lot of uses of the tag by itself, and it's rarely used in conjunction with other languages that aren't JavaScript, so I guess it won't hurt anything.  I went ahead and applied `lang-js` to the `d3.js` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) fixed this,  see his comments to my question above .

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTML comment in your answer to specify a language for syntax highlighting. From [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#syntax-highlighting):

> To manually specify the language of a code block, insert an HTML
>   comment like this before the block:
>
> ```
> <!-- language: lang-js -->
>
>     setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
> ```

You can also specify a language for all code blocks in the answer with:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-js -->
```

I've edited that into your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with that option!

Comment: Yeah, I agree it would probably be easier if it was picked up automatically, but thought this could be useful for some people. It took me ages to realise you could do this!

Comment: It's good to know indeed; especially when you have tags with conflicting highlighting languages.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to my question, but I'll remove it so that my feature request is clear for everyone.

Comment: If this can't be implemented I'll add it again later.